# how can i simplify count query from same table

Tags: php, mysql

hi i am trying to reduce the code how can i simplify these lines. please suggest edit if question not reach standards.

```
$invCount = $conn->query("SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM r_job_invitations WHERE id_job='".$_POST['JobId']."' and inv_st=1) as clginvcount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM r_job_invitations WHERE id_job='".$_POST['JobId']."' and inv_res=1) as clgaccptdcount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM r_job_invitations WHERE id_job='".$_POST['JobId']."' and inv_res=2) as clgrejectedcount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM r_job_invitations WHERE id_job='".$_POST['JobId']."' and inv_res=0) as clgnoresponsecount");
$invCountRes = $invCount->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: which count do you want exactly ?

Comment: and what do you mean with simplify, also use input validation for your POST variabeles and never inject them straight into a SQL statement. This code is highly vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I am trying to get 4 types of counts from one table total invites,yes,no,maybe. Check out the answer which I'ma gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only values 0,1,2 in coumn inv_res you can use this query and also please first validate your user input:

```
$jobId = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['JobId']);
SELECT 
    count(*), inv_res 
FROM  r_job_invitations 
WHERE 
    id_job ='".$jobId."' 
GROUP BY inv_res
```

If you have more values, use following

```
SELECT 
    count(*), inv_res 
FROM  r_job_invitations 
WHERE 
    id_job ='".$jobId."' AND 
    inv_res IN(0,1,2)
GROUP BY inv_res
```